# Angular 2 TypeScript how to find element in Array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have a Component and a Service:

Component:

```js
export class WebUserProfileViewComponent {
    persons: Person [];
    personId: number;
    constructor( params: RouteParams, private personService: PersonService) {
          
        
           this.personId = params.get('id');
           this.persons =  this. personService.getPersons();
           console.log(this.personId);  
        }
}
```

Service:

```js
@Injectable()
export class PersonService {
      getPersons(){
        var persons: Person[] = [
            {id: 1, firstName:'Hans', lastName:'Mustermann', email: 'mustermann@test.com', company:'Test', country:'DE'},
            {id: 2, firstName:'Muster', lastName:'Mustermann', email: 'mustermann@test.com', company:'test', country:'DE'},
            {id:3, firstName:'Thomas', lastName:'Mustermann', email: 'mustermannt@tesrt.com', company:'test', country:'DE'}
        ];
          
        return persons;
      }
}
```

I want to get the Person item with the ID ('personID'). The personID I get from `Routeparams`. For that I need the foreach loop? But I haven't found a solution for this.

Comment: You can find an element by Id like this persons.find(person => person.id === personId)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: Try always to get the data inside the ngOninit method lifecycle hook and not the constructor and try even static data to use observable with

Answer (score 319):

You need to use method [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
this.persons =  this.personService.getPersons().filter(x => x.id == this.personId)[0];
```

or [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
this.persons =  this.personService.getPersons().find(x => x.id == this.personId);
```

Comment: @SaravananNandhan, method `this.personService.getPersons()` returns `undefined`

Comment: @AndreiZhytkevich shouldn't we use triple equals?

Comment: @antonioplacerda, yes, that will do. However, for this question it is not too important.

Comment: At first that code seems cryptic for me, but it might help to read "find(x => x.id == this.personId"
as
"find x, where x's id equals this person id"
I don't know about other people, but for me this is much easier to remember.

Answer (score 97):

Assume I have below array:

```
Skins[
    {Id: 1, Name: "oily skin"}, 
    {Id: 2, Name: "dry skin"}
];
```

If we want to get item with `Id = 1` and `Name = "oily skin"`, We'll try as below:

```
var skinName = skins.find(x=>x.Id == "1").Name;
```

The result will return the skinName is "Oily skin".

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: How would you do this for an array initially empty then dynamically populated... there seems to be an issue while compiling.... the property e.g Id becomes unknown.

Comment: Hello @rey_coder, I think we should take a check if array not null before we implement to get array's element items. Like:

testArray = [];
testArrayItem = testArray.length>0? testArray.find(x=>x.Id== 1).Name: 'testArray null';
console.log(testArrayItem);

Comment: Hi @hai-dinh, That sorted the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You could combine `.find` with arrow functions and destructuring. [Take this example from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Find_an_object_in_an_array_by_one_of_its_properties).

```
const inventory = [
  {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
  {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
  {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];

const result = inventory.find( ({ name }) => name === 'cherries' );

console.log(result) // { name: 'cherries', quantity: 5 }
```

Answer (score 10):

Transform the data structure to a map if you frequently use this search

```
mapPersons: Map<number, Person>;

// prepare the map - call once or when person array change
populateMap() : void {
    this.mapPersons = new Map();
    for (let o of this.personService.getPersons()) this.mapPersons.set(o.id, o);
}
getPerson(id: number) : Person {
    return this.mapPersons.get(id);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

from TypeScript you can use native JS array filter() method:

```
let filteredElements=array.filter(element => element.field == filterValue);
```

it returns an array with only matching elements from the original array (0, 1 or more)

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 5):

Use this code in your service:

```
return this.getReports(accessToken)
        .then(reports => reports.filter(report => report.id === id)[0]);
```